# javascript file or folder lookup and import

Tags: javascript

I have a folder structure like in my `Reactjs` app:

```
rootFolder
    -folder1
        -file1
    -folder2
        -file2
    -folder3
        -folder4
            -folder5
                -file5
```

Here In `file5` I want to import class from `file1`.

Lets say `file1` has class `Class1`
I want to import it like:

`import Class1 from ..../folder1/file1`

but it is not being imported. Its giving me import error

What is wrong in here ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typo. Instead of 
`import Class1 from '..../folder1/file1'`  should be `import Class1 from '../../../folder1/file1'`

`../` means that you go to one folder above.

Hope it will help you

Comment: Still not import `can not resolve file or directory`

Comment: I want to import class from file1 to file5

Comment: @aryan look at my answer now, you should have `../../../` and then `/folder1/file1`